# Looking for transistor specifications

Tags: identification, triac

I'm looking for a transistor. Unfortunately the transistor is so burnt that I can't see the part number. It's from ST and I found a circuit diagram for the board, but there seems to be no model no in the circuit diagram.
Could somone maybe help me with that?

Thank you very much

[image: Burnt Transistor]

[image: Circuit diagram]

[image: Circuit diagram (zoomed)]

Comment: That symbol's for a thyristor, not a transistor.

Comment: Triac not Thyristor.

Comment: @RoyC  GE SCR manual ('72) says the [following](https://i.imgur.com/aEoPKAt.png), which would include the triac (or TRIAC) as a type of thyristor. I don't have access to the 1964 IEC document.

Comment: Ah, Thank you. I didn't know about TRIACs. Did only Laptop repairs - there a TRIAC is not a thing (Maybe for the Powersupply) :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will take a SWAG: it is a ST BTA?? triac. I would try a BTA16-800BWRG from STMicroelectronics. That is overkill but looking at the circuit board it was running hot. A small heat sink added would not hurt anything. It was apparently also shorted with a probe or something. It is only a few bucks which should not matter as you are not building thousands. This could also indicate you have a motor failing.

Answer (score 4):

Can't be sure from what is visible but it sure looks like a smoked [ST BTA12](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/aa/8c/87/f6/18/fc/46/93/CD00002267.pdf/files/CD00002267.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00002267.pdf) triac.